# How can I search for other countries using Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I need to be able to search for a product based on barcode, keyword or ASIN and show the results from amazon.co.uk, amazon.com, amazon.de and amazon.fr (UK, USA, Germany and France).

Is that possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: @iwanyeo did you ever implement this? I would be interested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the bottom of this [page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/), you will find links to the various Locales where this Product Advertising API works.

However, you need to make a separate subscription to each one of these different APIs. In other words, you need a different `AssociateTag`, `AccessKeyId` and a `secret key` in order to access those different APIs.

You can implement a search engine that uses all of those APIs in sequence. Start by searching for the product in the US API, then UK, then DE, ... You can encapsulate this complexity in a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), so that your client simply makes a single call to search. You might also encounter some performance issues with this idea, so the use of cache (and common sense) is advisable.